# Find the optimal sorting algorithm by inversions number/Pearson's r

Tags: algorithm, sorting, inversion

is it possible to find a optimal sorting algorithm with a given number of elements in a presorted sequence and a inversions number or a Pearson's r of that sequence?

For example I have a presorted sequence of `262143` elements.

The maximum amount of inversions is donated by `(n(n-1))/2` where `n` is the number of elements in the sequence (see [here page 2](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/mehlhorn18.pdf) for this assumption). For this example the maximum is therefor `34359345153`.

Now the number of inversions of my presorted sequence is `1299203725` which is `3.78%` of the maximum. My Pearson's r is `0.9941`. By my understanding this should be a presorted sequence with a high "sortedness" (Please correct my if I'm wrong).

I found many references to the number of inversions and the Person's r as a way to define the "sortedness" of a sequence but I could not get some kind of comparison for which number of elements and inversions/Pearson's r which sorting algorithm is the preferred one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably very hard to beat the worst-case O(n log n) time of traditional sorting algorithms like merge sort, if you assume that your sorting algorithm is comparison-based. I believe in order to do as good or better you would probably have to assume that the number of inversions is O(n log n), much smaller than the worst-case O(n^2). Then something like bubble sort could run as fast as O(n) time if you have O(n) inversions and you keep swapping backwards as long as an element forms an inversion with its left neighbor.